# Ruby: Compare two parsed json while ignoring certain keys

Tags: ruby, json, rspec

I am trying to compare two parsed json objects using `json` gem and `Rspec` syntax in Ruby.

```
JSON.parse(@response.body).should == JSON.parse(File.read(file_path))
```

Is there any way that I can exclude some of the (key, value) pair(s) while doing the comparison?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no built-in possibility for doing so, but you are always free to `map-reduce` your hashes in the following manner:

```
JSON.parse(@response.body).reject { |k, v| v > 5 }.should == …
```

E.g.:

```
excluded = %w(bad wrong)
JSON.parse(@response.body).reject { |k, v| excluded.include? k}.should == …
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it possible to reject a nested key?

Comment: Explicitely—no. I would in such a case use a `map` method on hashes, excluding whatever you need from the resulting hash.